# How to call a function from a nested object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `obj` that has a nested object `comments` and a function `startMatch` that returns an object like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.comments = {
  startMatch: function(matchStrings, isCaseSensitive) {
    return {
      subscribe: function(delegate) {
        delegate('test')
        const unsubscribe = () => {
          console.log("unsubscribed");
        };
      }
    };
  }
};

var subscription = obj.comments.startMatch([], false).subscribe(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

I would like to make this in such a way that I could call the `unsubscribe` function like this:

```
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

But I can't figure out how to do it without getting the unsubscribe undefined error.

Comment: You can return the unsubscribe function or pass in a unsubscribe callback as second parameter to your subscribe function

Comment: Well, maybe you should do `return unsubscribe` from `subscribe` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the simplest way:

```
var obj = {};
obj.comments = {
  startMatch: function(matchStrings, isCaseSensitive) {
    return {
      subscribe: function(delegate) {
        delegate('test');
          return { unsubscribe: () => console.log("unsubscribed") }
      }
    };
  }
};

var subscription = obj.comments.startMatch([], false).subscribe(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});

subscription.unsubscribe();
```